# Sentiment Analysis using Java

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

What are the opensource options for sentiment analysis in Java, preferably one that is compatible with Apache OpenNLP?

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Comment: [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154) and hence are off-topic – we will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what features do you need, where should it integrate, are there any license/cost considerations?